# How to connect PCF8951 with Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, i2c, analog-to-digital

I want to connect PCF8951 with Raspberry Pi

I'm following: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba2Mt.png): https://www.sunfounder.com/learn/sensor-kit-v2-0-for-raspberry-pi-b-plus/lesson-13-pcf8591-sensor-kit-v2-0-for-b-plus.html

But when using the command sudo i2cdetect -y 1, Can't find I2C device/address. Why??? [Not disabled jumper P4 P5 P6]

[image: Result]

Comment: If you edit your question and add the screen output as text with "code" format, I will perhaps read and try to assist you, the picture is worthless!

Answer (score 1):

A number of possibilities.

1. The device is not properly connected to the bus.
2. The device is broken.
3. One of the Pi's SDA or SCL GPIO is bust.
4. One of the Pi's SDA or SCL GPIO is not in the correct mode.

You need to **edit further information into your question** if you want us to help more.

Comment: Can clarify please how can I know if my Pi's SDA ou SCL GPIO are bust or are not in the correct mode? I used to work with my pcf8951 but I have the same problem I couldn't detect the address of my device and the red led is on , how to know also if it is the converter that is broken ?